# Makefile process multiline output

Tags: makefile, guidance-automation-tool

I have a command which outputs lines. I would like to process each line in parallel with Make.

```
target:
  command > $@
```

so now, I have a file called "target". In shell, I would do

```
   while read -r line; do
       echo "$line"
    done < target
```

Comment: make does not process lines of files. It automates the processing of files, producing other files. So if you would like to use make to process in parallel the lines produced by your `command`, the best option is probably to split that in as many different files. Is it OK for you? But if the only characteristic of make you are interested in is parallel processing, you should probably use something else. Did you look at [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of parallel. I will consider that.

Comment: How is the shell example parallel?